# Modifying a local template

Tags: customization, templates

I'm a novice in Wordpress, I ordered a custom template and installed it.
Now that I want to modify the text in the template I found that I need to change it in the database in multiple rows in table wp_posts.

Is that the ways templates are being stored in WP? I thought that it would be in a regular html file or something like that.

Thank you

Comment: No, that's not usual. But you'll need to post the offending code if you want the view of users here on what has happened and what to do about it.

Comment: Thank you @cjbj, I only try to understand why is the template placed in the database? shouldn't it be as a regular html/css file in the Wordpress directory? it is very hard to maintain a website that it stored in a database

Comment: The template shouldn't be in the database. But I cannot say why it was done in this case if I have no background information. Since you're a novice I'm also not completely sure whether you mean the same thing with 'template' as I do. That's why I asked for code, for instance your `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you @cjbi, this is the website: http://new.comelody.com/ the template is a child of Salient

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of template you wish to change. Generally templates have a suffix to them. Some examples:

## Page Suffix

These are used for templates on either individual pages or specific theme templates.

- page.php
- page-products.php
- page-cars.php

## Single Suffix

Used for custom post types or just individual post types. The type of post type defined at the end is what the template will be used for.

- single.php
- single-books.php
- single-vans.php

There are others, and should you wish to learn more about these, you can take a look at the documentation provided by WordPress here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/

Dependant on the theme, the template files may be located in a folder named /templates or /template-parts or something along those lines.

On a side note: Since you mentioned you brought a custom theme, there might be options to customise the theme in the WordPress customiser, which can be found in the admin panel of your blog.

Hope this helps and Happy Theming!!

Answer (score -1):

Templates are in /wp-content/themes/NAME_OF_TEMPLATE/